# Defining constant array in C

Tags: c, linux

I know, there have been some questions with a similar topic in SO, but none of them are really answering the problem.

Usually you define a constant array as follows:

```
const char arr[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
```

The question "*can I use the #define directive to do the exact same?*" was mostly answered with a simple *no*, however I stumbled across a header file on lxr, looking for a struct. Thats when I found this:

```
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_any;
#define IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_loopback;
#define IN6ADDR_LOOPBACK_INIT { { { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_linklocal_allnodes;
#define IN6ADDR_LINKLOCAL_ALLNODES_INIT \
    { { { 0xff,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_linklocal_allrouters;
#define IN6ADDR_LINKLOCAL_ALLROUTERS_INIT \
    { { { 0xff,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_interfacelocal_allnodes;
#define IN6ADDR_INTERFACELOCAL_ALLNODES_INIT \
    { { { 0xff,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_interfacelocal_allrouters;
#define IN6ADDR_INTERFACELOCAL_ALLROUTERS_INIT \
    { { { 0xff,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 } } }
extern const struct in6_addr in6addr_sitelocal_allrouters;
#define IN6ADDR_SITELOCAL_ALLROUTERS_INIT \
    { { { 0xff,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 } } }
#endif
```

(found at http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12-rc6/source/include/linux/in6.h)

Does this only work in the kernel or is there a specific way to accomplish this for any array?

Comment: You can't "*use the #define directive to do the exact same*" simply because the array definition is allocating some memory and filling it with some values, while the `#define` directive does nothing except defining some string substitution..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well yeah, but how do you explain the snippet from above, taken from a header file in the kernel? Although its just substitution, there are cases where the defined array is assigned to a variable just like anything else.

Comment: Explain what? It is the sting substitution as stated. `IN6ADDR_LINKLOCAL_ALLNODES_INIT` can be used anywhere where `{ { { 0xff,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 } } }` can be used.

Comment: Even when doing the same as in the code above, compiling the file won't work, causing an *test.c:3:13: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
 #define ARR { { { 0xff,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2 } } }* error.

Comment: to be clear you CAN use #define to create an initialized array. There may be some fancy things you are trying to do that cant be done but there is no generic reason why it cant be done. You should show what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Show the exact file generating this error.

Comment: My bad, I now understand it fully, answered to dbush's answer below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "The question "can I use the #define directive to do the exact same?" was mostly answered with a simple no" - that's wrong. The answer is "yes", as shown below. Compound literals allow one to do that with `#define`.

Comment: CD does not support user-defined constants.`const char arr[]` is not a constant array, but you guarantee you will not change that array _variable_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #defines shown above are used as a shorthand to initialize a particular type of struct.

Using the example you gave:

```
const char arr[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
```

You could also do the following:

```
#define ARR_INIT {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
const char arr[] = ARR_INIT;
```

Comment: ah now it makes sense, since #define is just a substitution, you need an actual array to assign the value from the define directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  C99/C11 compound literal:

```
#define MY_ARR (const char []){0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
```

Defines without the "type-cast" (initializer macros) will only work correctly with if the left hand side is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you quoted are *initializers*, which are intended to be used as

```
struct in6_addr addr_any = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT;
```

These initializers don't form self-sufficient expressions in C and cannot be used in any other role. So, no, by themselves they are not `#define` version of your `arr`. You won't be able to use them as, say, `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT[5]`.

Replacing your `arr` with a `#define` would require using *compound literals* (a feature of C99 and later)

```
#define arr (const char []) {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03}
```

You can use these initializers to build compound literals, as in

```
(struct in6_addr) IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT.s6_addr[8]
```

but it is not clear whether this is what you want to do.